# Amazon Web Service Lambda using Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, gson, aws-lambda

Hi I am doing a small POC with AWS Lambda using Java,
I want to test a simple Lambda function call, which will accept a string
I am using Google's Gson to convert String to Json and use it in my demo program.

**I referred this documentation for my demo -**
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/get-started-step4-optional.html
and 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-create-jar-pkg-maven-and-eclipse.html

**Here's my Project directory structure -**
[image]

I am getting an error when **I call the Lambda function with the following String** -

```
"{'name':'Aniruddha','age':'25'}"
```

**Here's the error -**

```
{
  "errorMessage": "com/google/gson/GsonBuilder",
  "errorType": "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "example.Hello.myHandler(Hello.java:11)",
    "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)",
    "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)",
    "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)",
    "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)"
  ]
}
```

**Here's my Handler function -**

package example;

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class Hello {
    public String myHandler(String request, Context context) {

        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = builder.create();

        QueryParams queryParams = gson.fromJson(request, QueryParams.class);
        System.out.println("Name is: "+queryParams.getName()+" Age is: "+queryParams.getAge());

        LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();
        logger.log("received a Lambda request");

        String message = "Hey there! " + queryParams.getName() + " you are " + queryParams.getAge() + " years old";
        return message;
    }
}
```

**This is my PoJo -**

```
package example;

public class QueryParams {

    String name;
    int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

**This is the pom.xml -**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>doc-examples</groupId>
  <artifactId>lambda-java-example</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>lambda-java-example</name>
  <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-lambda-java-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>       
   </dependencies>
     <build>
       <plugins>
         <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.3</version>
           <configuration>
             <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
           </configuration>
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <phase>package</phase>
               <goals>
                 <goal>shade</goal>
               </goals>
             </execution>
           </executions>
         </plugin>
       </plugins>
     </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Don't know AWS, but it looks like GSON is not on the classpath. Perhaps you forgot to deploy it with your code? Or were you expecting it to already be there?

Comment: @Andreas sorry I'm new to Java, can you tell me what to do? I did a clean and build and then did a Maven install to get the Jar, did I miss anyting?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you have followed the steps described in the dicumentaton to create your packege: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-java-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

Comment: Hi @JBNizet  I did follow this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-create-jar-pkg-maven-and-eclipse.html , can you help me where did I go wrong? I've updated the question and added an Image to show the directory structure.

Comment: There is no maven shade plugin in your pom. So you haven't followed the steps until the end. The mven shade plugin is what allows building a jar containing not only your code, but all the dependencies (Gson in this case) that your code needs.

Comment: @JBNizet Appologies, thanks for bring it to my notice, I added the plugin as per the doc, one of the steps is saying In the Edit Configuration windows, type package shade:shade in the Goals box.  I am using Spring Tool Suite, any idea how I should go about it, sorry, I'm a novice at Java.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-create-jar-pkg-maven-no-ide.html

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks that solved it! Big help, thanks a ton Sir :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright as **@JBNizet** advised (check question's comments), 
It solved the issue. 
**Here's the pom.xml we need -**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>doc-examples</groupId>
  <artifactId>lambda-java-example</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>lambda-java-example</name>
  <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-lambda-java-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>       
   </dependencies>
     <build>
       <plugins>
         <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.3</version>
           <configuration>
             <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
           </configuration>
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <phase>package</phase>
               <goals>
                 <goal>shade</goal>
               </goals>
             </execution>
           </executions>
         </plugin>
       </plugins>
     </build>
</project>
```